# Case-When table name in Hive

Tags: hive

How can I CASE WHEN table name in a Hive SELECT query?

I want to do something to the effect of -

```
SELECT col1, col2 
FROM
  CASE ${PARAM}
    WHEN 'val1' THEN table1
    WHEN 'val2' THEN table2
```

Comment: I don't believe that is valid syntax in any flavor of SQL.

Comment: Can you describe your case in detail , because this approach is syntactically is wrong . Case When Then can only be used in Select Clause .

Comment: @RajatMishra I want to generate output from different source tables based on an input parameter in my hive script. I completely understand the syntax I described isn't valid but my question is what valid hive syntax can be used to achieve the objective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible. Rewrite your query like this:

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM table1 WHERE '${PARAM}' = 'val1' --only one subquery will be executed
union all
SELECT col1, col2 FROM table2 WHERE '${PARAM}' = 'val2'
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. I will go with this approach.